# Is there any way I could print these two linked lists side by side, instead of being on top of each other?

Tags: c++, function, class, data-structures, linked-list

`appendName` is a function that inserts a string node at the end of the first linked list.

`appendPrice` is a function that inserts an integer node at the end of the second linked list.

`printName` is a function that prints the first linked list (linked list 1)

`printPrice` is a function that prints the second linked list (linked list 2)

```
struct nodeName
{
    string Name;
    nodeName *link;
};

void appendName(nodeName** head_name_ref, string new_Name)
{
    nodeName* new_name_node = new nodeName();
    nodeName *last = *head_name_ref;
    new_name_node->Name = new_Name;
    new_name_node->link = NULL;
    if (*head_name_ref == NULL)
    {
        *head_name_ref = new_name_node;
        return;
    }
    while (last->link != NULL)
    {
        last = last->link;
    }
    last->link = new_name_node;
    return;
}

void printName(nodeName *node)
{
    while (node != NULL)
    {
        cout<<" "<<node->Name<<endl;
        node = node->link;
    }
}

struct nodePrice
{
    int Price;
    nodePrice *link;
};

void appendPrice(nodePrice** head_ref, int new_Price)
{
    nodePrice* new_node = new nodePrice();
    nodePrice *last = *head_ref;
    new_node->Price = new_Price;
    new_node->link = NULL;
    if (*head_ref == NULL)
    {
        *head_ref = new_node;
        return;
    }
    while (last->link != NULL)
    {
        last = last->link;
    }
    last->link = new_node;
    return;
}

void printPrice(nodePrice *node)
{
    while (node != NULL)
    {
        cout<<" "<<node->Price<<endl;
        node = node->link;
    }
}

int main()
{
    nodeName* headingNode1 = NULL;
    appendName(&headingNode1, "item#1");
    appendName(&headingNode1, "item#2");

    nodePrice* pricingNode1 = NULL;
    appendPrice(&pricingNode1, 6);
    appendPrice(&pricingNode1, 14);

    cout<<"Created Linked list is"<<endl;
    printName(headingNode1);
    printPrice(pricingNode1);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is a picture of the output:

[image]

Comment: You'd have to iterate both at the same time. Get an item from list one, print it, get an item from list two, print it, print newline, get next litem from list one, print it, get next item from list two, print it, print newline ...

Comment: Is a smarter node that stores both data items and use one list instead of having a different list for each data item an option?

Answer (score 1):

You can add another struct to include both lists:

```
struct nodeList
{
    nodeName* names;
    nodePrice* prices;
};
```

A new function to print the lists:

```
void printList(nodeList* list)
{
    while (list->names != NULL && list->prices != NULL)
    {
        std::cout << " " << list->names->Name << std::endl;
        list->names = list->names->link;
        std::cout << " " << list->prices->Price << std::endl;
        list->prices = list->prices->link;
    }
}
```

And in the main function:

```
nodeList* list  = new nodeList();
list->names = headingNode1;
list->prices = pricingNode1;

std::cout << "Created Linked list is" << std::endl;
//printName(headingNode1);
//printPrice(pricingNode1);
printList(list);
```

Output:

```
Created Linked list is
 item#1
 6
 item#2
 14
```

Comment: This, aggregating the data and combining the lists into one list, is the most logical solution. I'd replace `std::cout << " " << list->names->Name << std::endl;` with `std::cout << " " << list->names->Name << '\t';` or similar to get the output looking like `item#1
      6`

Answer (score 0):

```
void printNameAndPrice(nodeName1 *node1, nodeName2 *node2){

while (node1 != NULL && node2 != NULL)
{
    cout<<" "<<node1->Name<<endl;
    cout<<" "<<node2->Price<<endl;

    node1 = node1->link;
    node2 = node2->link;
}}
```

**Yes you can!** you just want to add them in one method.

So the idea is to read them in parallel then update till the end.

Note: you can do the same in appending elements to the Linked List

Comment: The problem is the current design has 2 separate linked lists with separate nodes. And I agree that it should be 1 list instead.

Comment: void printNameAndPrice(nodeName1 *node1, nodeName2 *node2){
while (node != NULL)
{
    cout<<" "<<node1->Name<<endl;
    cout<<" "<<node2->Price<<endl;
    node1 = node1->link;node2 = node2->link;
}}   ok you can just pass the 2 LL and print , update till the end (here am assuming they have the same size )

Comment: @HasanS. That unreadable chunk of code would be better placed in your answer, not as a comment.  Nobody's going to read it there, especially as you haven't used markdown.